# ibase_execute just hangs when there is a deadlock

Tags: php, firebird, firebird2.1

Setup: firebirdsql 2.1.3 win32, php 5.3 (installed with xampp)
When I try to update a record that's edited in a desktop app or IBexpert, and there is a deadlock, ibase_execute just hangs, does not return any value nor raises an exception.
When there's no deadlock, everything works fine.
Any ideas how to catch this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

By default, the transactions are IBASE_WAIT, so it waits until the record is no longer edited.
You have to start a transaction with the IBASE_NOWAIT option to get an immediate response in a deadlock situation.